# python crawling beautifulsoup how to crawl several pages?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, web-crawler

Please Help. 
I want to get all the company names of each pages and they have 12 pages.

http://www.saramin.co.kr/zf_user/jobs/company-labs/list/page/1 
http://www.saramin.co.kr/zf_user/jobs/company-labs/list/page/2
-- this website only changes the number.

So Here is my code so far.
Can I get just the title (company name) of 12 pages? 
Thank you in advance.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

maximum = 0
page = 1

URL = 'http://www.saramin.co.kr/zf_user/jobs/company-labs/list/page/1'
response = requests.get(URL)
source = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

whole_source = ""
for page_number in range(1, maximum+1):
URL = 'http://www.saramin.co.kr/zf_user/jobs/company-labs/list/page/' + str(page_number)
response = requests.get(URL)

whole_source = whole_source + response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(whole_source, 'html.parser')
find_company = soup.select("#content > div.wrap_analysis_data > div.public_con_box.public_list_wrap > ul > li:nth-child(13) > div > strong")

for company in find_company:
print(company.text)
```

[---------Output of one page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MApYW.png)

[---------page source :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opbx0.png)

Comment: You have described your expectation, but what is the current output of your code?What issue are you facing? And I think while posting you missed the indentations of your loops, please correct it to clearly understand your code

Comment: In you for loop, after fetching response, you can just select the <title> tag from each page.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to remove all the `headers` and get only the `string` of the company name?
Basically, you can use the `soup.findAll` to find the list of company in the format like this:

> ```
> <strong class="company"><span>중소기업진흥공단</span></strong>
> ```

Then you use the `.find` function to extract information from the `<span>` tag:

> ```
> <span>중소기업진흥공단</span>
> ```

After that, you use `.contents` function to get the string from the `<span>` tag:

> `'중소기업진흥공단'`

So you write a loop to do the same for each page, and make a list called `company_list` to store the results from each page and append them together.

Here's the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

maximum = 12

company_list = [] # List for result storing
for page_number in range(1, maximum+1):
    URL = 'http://www.saramin.co.kr/zf_user/jobs/company-labs/list/page/{}'.format(page_number) 
    response = requests.get(URL)
    print(page_number)
    whole_source = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(whole_source, 'html.parser')
    for entry in soup.findAll('strong', attrs={'class': 'company'}): # Finding all company names in the page
        company_list.append(entry.find('span').contents[0]) # Extracting name from the result
```

The `company_list` will give you all the company names you want

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out eventually. Thank you for your answer though!

[image : code captured in jupyter notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLJKU.png)

Here is my final code.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

company_list=[]
for n in range(12):
    url = 'http://www.saramin.co.kr/zf_user/jobs/company-labs/list/page/{}'.format(n+1)
    webpage = urlopen(url)
    source = BeautifulSoup(webpage,'html.parser',from_encoding='utf-8')
    companys = source.findAll('strong',{'class':'company'})

    for company in companys:
    company_list.append(company.get_text().strip().replace('\n','').replace('\t','').replace('\r',''))

file = open('company_name1.txt','w',encoding='utf-8')

for company in company_list:
file.write(company+'\n')

file.close()
```

Comment: If the problem is solved, can you please select the best answer? So that people know this answer is resolved.